# Obtaining wp_list_pages in a Wordpress widget

Tags: wordpress

I am creating my own little widget sitemap to put in my footer. Here's my code:

```
function widget($args, $instance)
{
extract( $args );
$title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
echo $before_widget;
if ( $title ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; }

// WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
    // ?> THIS IS A TEST! <?php

?><ul><?php
    wp_list_pages('title_li=<h2>MAP OF THE SITE</h2>&sort_column=menu_order&depth=0&include=57,55,59,61,63,65,192'); 
?></ul><?php

echo $after_widget;     
}
```

but looks like `wp_list_pages` doesn't return anything. Not even the title. Indeed if I uncomment that "this is a test" then it's shown.
The strange thing is the same `wp_list_page` is implemented also in `header.php` to obtain menus.

Answer (score 0):

First rule when creating `Wordpress` custom functions is to check if function with the same name already exists.

```
<?php if (!function_exists("function_name")) {...} ?>
```

Second rule is to name your function with really unique name, in order to avoid conflicts. In your case this function already exists, that's why you cannot extract the data as you expect...

One more thing, I assume you will put this whole function code in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Hello budiony, first thanks for your answer, but I forgot to explain in more detail... I am creating a plugin to widgetize extending WP_Widget class.. so about the function it works well since when uncommenting the "THIS IS A TEST" thing I can read it on frontend... it's about the wp_list_pages which doesn't return pages to me... any ideas?...

Comment: Hello, did you check what WP codex say about this function? See here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: Thanks budiony... solved by myself... had wrong includes, now it works perfect using wp_page_menu()